# How can I tab in and out of a combobox in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to use the tab key for expediency and type a time value to look like the image below with a combobox, so an hour can be typed, [tab key] a minute can be typed [tab key] and a default value of AM is displayed, but hitting the A key or P key will toggle back and forth between the read only combobox options of AM and PM, as well as the ability to shift tab back into the combobox if needed.

Right now, the tab key will take me to the cell behind the combobox. I've tried the code below but nothing happens. How can I implement this?

[image]

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
        ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case vbKeyTab
            Me.ComboBox1.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        Case vbKeyReturn
            Me.ComboBox1.TopLeftCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't have time to try it right now, but you might have to add the field values for hours and minutes as text boxes, and put it all inside a frame.

Comment: It sounds like that would allow me to tab in and out of those 3 fields only, which is not what I'm looking for.

I'd like it to function as tabbing works with all other cells on the sheet.